# Two lines in space must intersect to be perpendicular between them?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Or is not necessary and why? Where is the definition?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular), two lines are perpendicular if they _meet_ or _intersect_ at a right angle

Comment: My school geometry defines two lines $d,e$ in space to be perpendicular, iff after a parallel transport of the one line $e$ so that the "moved line" $e'$ intersects the other one, we have in plane $d\perp e'$. This terminology is useful when dealing with the theorem of three perpendiculars, or when claiming "if a line $d$ is perpendicular on two lines $e,f$ generating a plane $\pi$, then $d\perp \pi$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "perpendicular between them". If two lines are *skew*, then there is a line perpendicular to both of them.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3075946/693161) may shed light on your question.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, Carlitos?

Comment: Thank you very much. Andrew Chin link clarified my doubt.